# Auto Class including and Instance creation PHP

Tags: php, oop, class

Currently in an application i include classes from a directory (any number of classes could be dropped into this directory). Although i would like to go a step further and be able to create an array of class instances or class names **CLASS** from these files... is this possible when the class files are dropped into the folder? below is the code i currently use to include the files (php4 compat)

```
// Include custom field types, as drop-ins
$include_files = (array) glob( METAMAKER_FIELDS_DIR."*.php" );
if( is_array($include_files) ) {

    foreach($include_files as $filename) {
        if (!empty($filename) && strstr($filename, 'php')) {
            include_once($filename);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you a bit hyper-paranoid about the return of `glob` being an array? :)

Comment: you need to use Autoload (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Comment: LOL @ Deceze ... yes i guess. I did not see that

Comment: @Dezigo this is true although needs to be php4 compat and the main point is i need to be able to instantiate the classes without knowing what the class names are from these files possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join us in the 21st century and use [Autoloading](http://php.net/language.oop5.autoload). This is especially recommended, because with your approach its more complicated to ensure, that every dependency is resolved in the right order. Just don't do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're including the class files, you can use [get_declared_classes()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php) to get a list of class names. Constructing objects might be a little harder depending on what their constructors are like. If none of the constructors take (required) parameters, you could iterate through the list and construct one of each. Otherwise you may need to use reflection to work out what arguments you need to pass to each class.

You might want to ask yourself why you are doing this and whether you actually need one instance of each class. It sounds what you might need is some kind of [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) or [Service Locator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern).

Comment: All the classes will follow an inheritance and structure that is pre defined. although wont get_declared_classes() get all classes that have been declared...

Answer (score 0):

If your Class name and file name are the same you can create a `$className` from `$filename` and create an instance and store it in `$dict[md5($filename)] = new $className`

However you are kind of re inventing autoload

Comment: how can i then instantiate these classes without knowing what they are? i think i will move into _autoload... but i will have to convince client to go to php 5